# How to get the range of valid Numpy data types?

Tags: python, numpy, types

I'm interested in finding for a particular Numpy type (e.g. `np.int64`, `np.uint32`, `np.float32`, etc.) what the range of all possible valid values is (e.g. `np.int32` can store numbers up to `2**31-1`). Of course, I guess one can theoretically figure this out for each type, but is there a way to do this at run time to ensure more portable code?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Quoting from a numpy discussion list:

> That information is available via `numpy.finfo()` and `numpy.iinfo()`:
>
> ```
> In [12]: finfo('d').max
> Out[12]: 1.7976931348623157e+308
>
> In [13]: iinfo('i').max
> Out[13]: 2147483647
>
> In [14]: iinfo('uint8').max
> Out[14]: 255
> ```

Link [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg09903.html).

Answer (score 66):

You can use [`numpy.iinfo(arg).max`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html) to find the max value for integer types of `arg`, and [`numpy.finfo(arg).max`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) to find the max value for float types of `arg`.

```
>>> numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint64).min
0
>>> numpy.iinfo(numpy.uint64).max
18446744073709551615L
>>> numpy.finfo(numpy.float64).max
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> numpy.finfo(numpy.float64).min
-1.7976931348623157e+308
```

`iinfo` only offers `min` and `max`, but `finfo` also offers useful values such as `eps` (the smallest number > 0 representable) and `resolution` (the approximate decimal number resolution of the type of `arg`).