# Power of a decimal number producing OverflowError

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that returns **log10** values. On converting them to normal numbers, I obtain an overflow error.

> OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')

I checked the log values and this error occurs for say, **508.038057662**.

I reckon that while python easily performs **10**509**, this error must be due to the decimal points overflowing the register. Therefore I tried using numpy.float64 like such,

```
result = np.array([ (10**multiplicity(timeseries,om,ph,bins,pos_arr)) for ph in np.linspace(0,twopi,num = bins+1)], dtype = np.float64)
```

The error is the same. Am I declaring the **float64** wrong??

Here *multiplicity()* is the function that returns **log10** values. I require a "list" of values.

Comment: Well .... 10^509 is > 2^64 ... or am I missing something obvious, here?

Comment: `10**509 = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L ` using Python

Comment: Yeah, but as the answer-er below says, that's of type `long`, not of  type `float64`. You will note, perhaps unsurprisingly, that that datatype can only hold numbers up to 64 bits long.

Comment: 64-bit floats can represent numbers a lot larger than 2**64 (just not all of the integers in that range!), but nowhere near 10**509.

Comment: Yes true. Glad to understand the fundamentals better ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I reckon that while python easily performs 10**509, this error must be due to the decimal points overflowing the register.

The problem is not down to "the decimal points overflowing", but is caused by the data type you are using.

Python can happily calculate 10**509 as a `long` since [these have *unlimited precision*](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex):

```
>>> type(10**509)
<type 'long'>
```

However, this result is too big to store in a `float`:

```
>>> float(10**509)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

We can check the maximum `float` quite easily:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658714/range-of-valid-numpy-values) is seems that the Numpy `float64` has the same range of values as a standard `float` so using that instead isn't going to fix your problem.

Instead, you'll have to use one of the third-party modules that provide arbitrary precision floating points such as [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) or [bigfloat](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/).

Comment: Alright ok. So is there a way to convert my float to long then?? Or must I use bigfloat or mpmath??
Oh long doesnt take into account decimals rite?

Comment: `long` is for integers.  So `10**508` will be fine but `10**508.5` won't be.  So I think you're stuck with bigfloat or mpmath if you really do need to work with floating points that big.

Comment: GMPy is something you should look at if you are going for 3rd party.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the "un-log'd" values? I would keep them as logarithms for as long as possible (converting other arithmetic steps as appropriate).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I require to integrate the normal values. Using Stirling Approximation of log terms will cause some range of errors to occur. With Bigfloat working wonderfully, I can obtain perfect accuracy. Thanks all of you :)